# Splitting a special string into two ints

Tags: c#, split, integer

Is there a simple way to split a string like
        1234-5678
into two integers? 
I have 3 different types of those strings
        -5678
        5678-
        1234-5678
For the first one the lower limit is 0 and the upper one 5678.
For the second lower is 5678 und upper is 9999.
And the last one: lower = 1234, upper = 5678.

What I'm doing now is splitting the string on IndexOf("-") and then using TryParse(). But I think there might be a better or easier way to achieve this.

Thanks again!

Comment: For "give me a better way" question to be on-topic and not too broad you need to provide exact criteria of what you consider "better" like - less lines of code, no new strings, least number of statements (also this one probably would fit [CodeGolf.se] and not SO).

Comment: indexof and tryparse is exactly how i would do it

Comment: Except using split instead of indexof I can't think of a better attempt to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
string lower = "";
string upper = "";

string input = "1234-5678";

string[] array; 

array = input.split('-');

lower = array[0];
upper = array[1];
```

Comment: Note that this post neither answers the question (as there is no "into two ints" part) nor explains why this is any better than OP's solution.

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).